# Does Entity Framework 6 support .Net 3.5?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Does Entity Framework 6 support .Net 3.5?

(EF 6 is still in beta at the time of this writing.)

The documentation shows many benefits, performance and otherwise, when using .Net 4.5, but I cannot find a 'minimum requirements' page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the right hand side of the [EF6 Roadmap page on CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap) it says that .Net 4.0 is the System Requirement. Furthermore, when [reviewing the `csproj` files associated with EF6](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/EntityFramework/EntityFramework.csproj), it appears that only 4.0 and 4.5 are supplied as targets:

```
    ...
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\Strict.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugNet40|AnyCPU' ">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
```

In light of this I would say the answer is **No: EF6 does not support .Net 3.5**.

Comment: I totally agree with that finding. Thanks for confirming. Sorry about having to ask such a silly question on here.